# .io domains and git ssh blocked in Israel

Tags: israel, wifi

When using public transit WiFi such as the "ISRAEL-RAILWAY", I can't access any .io domains or push/pull from GitHub with an ssh key. I have to connect thru another network using my phone for WiFi sharing.

Why would these be firewalled?

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with the *.io domains; port is blocked, which is extremely common for public Wi-Fis. Not sure why you're surprised.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it's too technical, Super User is a better place.

Comment: A git push or pull is an incredibly network intensive task, which many open wifi operators want to avoid as it takes up network capacity disproportionately.

Comment: @Moo Compared to eg. Youtube, most git repos pushes are *nothing*

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk only *.io domains were blocked as far as I can tell. No other domains I tried to visit were blocked, so it's not a specific port blocked. I use a lot of sites that are *.io in my profession, and in my travels, I've never had this happen except in Israel, so yes, I'm surprised at the specificity of this block.

Comment: @NeanDerThal I don't want to know any technical details about this, only why the policy is in place to firewall this in Israeli govt run public WiFi. I have the same problem with the Ben Gurion airport's WiFi.